# Can we label prophet mohammed a Sunni because he was the messenger through Sunnah?

Tags: sunni, sunnah, prophets

I am new to Islam. So please be forgiving and understanding, I am curious to learn. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The term "sunni" has been invented after the death of the prophet PBUH, because many sect were created after his death, those who are the mainstream (90% of Muslim population) had to be labeled so that they can be distinguished from other sects. and I think your question is somehow doesn't make sense, why ? because sunnah means, the actions and the sayings of the prophet. and muslims who follow these are called sunni. So how would you label the prophet sunni? he is not following anyone?

Hope that helps

Answer (score -3):

No we can not, we can not be of any sect. See verse below:

Surah 6:159

Sahih International: Indeed, those who have divided their religion and become sects - you, [O Muhammad], are not [associated] with them in anything. Their affair is only [left] to Allah ; then He will inform them about what they used to do.
Pickthall: Lo! As for those who sunder their religion and become schismatics, no concern at all hast thou with them. Their case will go to Allah, Who then will tell them what they used to do.
Yusuf Ali: As for those who divide their religion and break up into sects, thou hast no part in them in the least: their affair is with Allah: He will in the end tell them the truth of all that they did.
Shakir: Surely they who divided their religion into parts and became sects, you have no concern with them; their affair is only with Allah, then He will inform them of what they did.
Muhammad Sarwar: Some of those who have divided their religion into different sects are not your concern. Their affairs are in the hands of God Who will show them all that they have done.
Mohsin Khan: Verily, those who divide their religion and break up into sects (all kinds of religious sects), you (O Muhammad SAW) have no concern in them in the least. Their affair is only with Allah, Who then will tell them what they used to do.
Arberry: Those who have made divisions in their religion and become sects, thou art not of them in anything; their affair is unto God, then He will tell them what they have been doing.

To me the above verse is as clear as daylight, corrupt and ignorant people will tell you different, Allah says that we should not be divided into sects, yet today majority of muslims are divided in sectarian groups even though Allah forbids it. The one group believing that they are on the right path and the other rejoicing in what they believe. You don’t have to believe what I say, you are free to believe whatever you want but Allah’s verse is clear.

Surah 4:82
Sahih International: Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an? If it had been from [any] other than Allah , they would have found within it much contradiction.

See above the question that Allah poses for us, don’t we reflect upon his book, had it been from anyone else they would find a lot of contradictions in it.

Just think for yourselves, how can each one of them be correct when they are all have different views??? Did Allah authorized the following of these humans and their views??? Nowhere in the Quran can I find this and if Allah left nothing out from the book then why is this not in his book?

Surah 6:38
Mohsin Khan: There is not a moving (living) creature on earth, nor a bird that flies with its two wings, but are communities like you. We have neglected nothing in the Book, then unto their Lord they (all) shall be gathered.

… because it is not for you to follow. We can now understand the reason as to why the Nabi of Allah will complain to Allah on the Day of Judgement that Muslims have deserted the Quran.

Surah25:30.
Sahih International: And the Messenger has said, "O my Lord, indeed my people have taken this Qur'an as [a thing] abandoned."
Pickthall: And the messenger saith: O my Lord! Lo! mine own folk make this Qur'an of no account.
Yusuf Ali: Then the Messenger will say: "O my Lord! Truly my people took this Qur'an for just foolish nonsense."
Shakir: And the Messenger cried out: O my Lord! surely my people have treated this Quran as a forsaken thing.
Muhammad Sarwar: The Messengers will say, "Lord, my people had abandoned this Quran."
Mohsin Khan: And the Messenger (Muhammad SAW) will say: "O my Lord! Verily, my people deserted this Quran (neither listened to it, nor acted on its laws and orders).
Arberry: The Messenger says, 'O my Lord, behold, my people have taken this Koran as a thing to be shunned.'

As you can see from the above verse the words “my people” (not the disbelievers they are already going to hell) have abandoned the Quran. I want you to look today how many religious practices today that we so sincerely practice upon is from Allah’s Quran?